# how to create multi language windows installer?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, installation, windows-installer

Whats the best way to create the multi language installer for Office Addin Deployment Setup?

Is it possible using VS.NET 2008, C# or do I need to use any 3rd party tool or like install shield 2009 ??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using InnoSetup, its free and supports multiple languages.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: I need some easytool, its bit complex as I need to write too much scripting for registry, strong name, etc....